# Use PNG as Background Map with collision detection

Tags: c#, xna, background-image, collision-detection, alpha

I have to make a pacman-like game and I tried many times but I cannot get it working. Here's what I did:

[image: Map]

This is the map. Everywhere I don't want collision to happen is transparent.

[image: Pac]

This is the pacman sprite. Also transparent, of course.

Here's my Map code:

```
mapTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D("11074582_10203478069210715_531544477_n");
mapPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
mapRectangle = new Rectangle((int)mapLeftPosition.X, (int)mapLeftPosition.Y, 800, 500);

spriteBatch.Draw(mapTexture, mapPosition, mapRectangle, Color.White);
```

And my Pacman code:

```
pacmanSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pacman");
pacmanPosition = new Vector2((width / 2), height / 2);
pacmanOrigin = new Vector2(pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Width / 2, pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Height / 2);
pacmanAnimatedRectangle = new Rectangle(currentFrame.X * frameSize.X, currentFrame.Y * frameSize.Y, frameSize.X, frameSize.Y);
spriteBatch.Draw(pacmanSprite, pacmanPosition, pacmanAnimatedRectangle, Color.White, rotation, pacmanOrigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

And the code I use to check if there is collision:

```
private bool IntersectsPixel()

     {
         Color[] colorData1 = new Color[pacmanSprite.Width * pacmanSprite.Height]; //Get every pixel of the sprite

         Color[] colorData2 = new Color[mapTexture.Width * mapTexture.Height];

         pacmanSprite.GetData<Color>(colorData1);

         mapTexture.GetData<Color>(colorData2);



         int top = Math.Max(pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Top, mapRectangle.Top);   //Get the square of both sprites

         int bottom = Math.Min(pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Bottom, mapRectangle.Bottom);

         int left = Math.Max(pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Left, mapRectangle.Left);

         int right = Math.Min(pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Right, mapRectangle.Right);

         for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)

         {

             for (int x = left; x < right; x++)

             {

                 Color A = colorData1[(y - pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Top) * (pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Width) + (x - pacmanAnimatedRectangle.Left)];

                 Color B = colorData2[(y - mapRectangle.Top) * (mapRectangle.Width) + (x - mapRectangle.Left)];


                 if (A.A != 0 && B.A != 0) //if collision spot is not transparent return true
                 {
                     return true;                    
                 }
             }

            }   

             return false;
```

So I think it should work, but no! It's all messed up:

[image: img]

Here it returns false on the collision detection, like it should.
But once I go up just a little:

[image: img]

It already returns true (detects collision). Why?? How is it possible, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the 'return true' and check coordinates and color values?

Comment: Which coordinates? the color values are really strange, and they make everything laggy on the update method, of course. But they change dramatically, from 0,0,0,0 to the color that is supposed to collide.

Comment: The x&y values. And the colliding colors are as expected (yellow and blueish)?

Comment: Could it be that the wrong pac shape is being checked? (You might create a pac-map with different colors for each shape to test this and look at the colliding pac color..)

Comment: don't use pixel collision on that, use simple box collision. no need to pixel collission, waste of resources in your case.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I tried using pacmanRectangle.Intersects(mapRectangle) and it always returns true.

Comment: @Taw the colliding color differ from (R:0,G:0,B:0,A:0) to the yellow and blueish expected. They value keeps changing dramatically.

Comment: @Davor: this is not really true as both the map and the pac man have rounded edges. In fact cutting corners is one important trick for playing real [pacman](http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior), which is  a much much more [complicted game](http://home.comcast.net/~jpittman2/pacman/pacmandossier.html) that it seems!!

Comment: You need to check the __coordinates__ of the first wrong colliding pixel!

Comment: if objects are round, then he could use circle-circle collision instead. simple function that receive center position and radius of objects.

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my code was checking for the upper left point in the rectangle and I was passing the center of the rectangle, which was messing up the entire code. Thank's anyway!